# How to check http status in springboot 3 using keycloak for token verification?

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, spring-3, userinfo

I want to create a method for `token verification` which will send a request to the `userinfo` endpoint of keycloak and send me back, true or false.

`true` if the response status is `200` (OK)
`false` if the response status is `401` (Unauthorized)

I don't actually need the user info payload. Only the response status is required. How I can achieve this using spring boot 3

Comment: Have you tried anything already to achieve this?

Comment: Please share your current appraoches, thoughts, archivements,... so we can try to help. Anyway at the spring-boot environment you can introduce spring-security and a `SecurityFilterChain`. This will always be called on authentifications and there you can configure calls to keycloak. Keep in mind that you need to whitelist the client at keycloak and configure a fix name/token from application to keycloak to make it work. More hints after showing work done :)